# How do I strip all leading and trailing punctuation in Python?

Tags: python, strip, punctuation

I know how to remove all the punctuation in a string.

```
import string

s = '.$ABC-799-99,#'

table = string.maketrans("","") # to remove punctuation
new_s = s.translate(table, string.punctuation)

print(new_s)
# Output
ABC79999
```

How do I strip all leading and trailing punctuation in Python? The desired result of `'.$ABC-799-99,#'` is `'ABC-799-99'`.

Comment: `s.strip(string.punctuation) `

Comment: I Googled your question's title and the linked duplicate was the very first result, with the exact solution you're looking for. Please do more research in the future.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, thx, I did research on SO.

Comment: SO's search isn't very good. Give Google a shot next time.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I'll keep in mind. thx again.

Comment: I do find it odd that the older question has 0 upvotes and this duplicate got 7, though. Oh well.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, it might be related to keywords. A possible reason is that `leading` or `trailing` is more common than `starting` in such a context.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You do exactly what you mention in your question, you just *str.strip* it.

```
from string import punctuation
s = '.$ABC-799-99,#'

print(s.strip(punctuation))
```

Output:

```
 ABC-799-99
```

*str.strip* can take multiple characters to remove.

If you just wanted to remove leading punctuation you could *str.lstrip*:

```
s.lstrip(punctuation)
```

Or *rstrip* any trailing punctuation:

```
 s.rstrip(punctuation)
```

Comment: Thx. If I'd keep `$`, `s.strip(string.punctuation.replace('$', ''))`, is it a better way?

Comment: @sparkandshine, no worries,i think  `.punctuation.replace('$', '')` is pretty good,  the other option is manually creating a string of punctuation characters minus $ and using that which I think would be a lot more arduous.